Equivalence between two definitions of a Seifert Fibered Homology Sphere
I am reading Savaliev's Invariants for Homology 3-spheres. Here, he defines the Seifert Fibered Homolgy Sphere as $\Sigma(a_1,...,a_n) = V_B(a_1,...,a_n) \cap S^{2n-1}$ where $V_B(a_1,...,a_n) = \{b_{i1}z_1^{a_1} + ... + b_{in}z_n^{a_n} = 0,\ i=1,2,...,n-2\}\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ and the $a_i$'s are pairwise coprime. (I am taking all the coefficients $b_{ij}$ to be $1$ for simplicity, Savaliev specifies the matrix $B=(b_{ij})$ must not have any of its maximal minors equal to zero). So this is the intersection of a complex $n$-dimensional surface with the $2n-1$ dimensional unit sphere.
Now, he also gives a topological description, which is much easier to picture. I quote him from his Lecture on the Topology of 3-manifolds:

Let $F = S^2-int(D_1^2\cup ... \cup D_n^2)$ be a $2$-sphere with the interiors of $n$ disjoint discs removed. The product $F\times S^1$ is a compact orientable $3$-manifold whose boundary consists of $n$ tori $(\partial D_i^2)\times S^1, i=1,...,n$. The fundamental group of $F\times S^1$ has a presentation $\langle x_1,...,x_n,h\ |\ hx_i = x_ih, x_1\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n=1\rangle$, where the generators $x_i$ are represented by the curves $\partial D_i^2$ oriented as the boundary curves of $F$. Suppose we are given $n$ pairs of relatively prime integers, $(a_i ,b_i),\ i=1,...,n$, with $a_i\geq 2$. We glue in $n$ solid tori so that the meridian of the $i$-th solid torus is glued to a curve on $(\partial D_i^2)\times S^1$ isotopic to $a_ix_i+b_ih$.

I was wondering if anyone could explain how are these two definitions (or constructions) equivalent? If you know of a book, paper, or other resource that might explain this equivalence I would also appreciate you sharing it. Thank you!
